# aiohttp.ClientSession.get and urllib.request.urlopen return different content

Tags: python-asyncio, urllib, aiohttp

I have a simple function that grabs HTML page from an URL

```py
import urllib.request

def download(url):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as resp:
        return resp.read(100)

url = 'https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/urllib/request.py'
print(download(url))
```

which returns, as expected, the HTML source of the page

```
> python test_urllib.py
b'\n\n\n\n\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en" data-color-mode="auto" data-light-theme="light" data-dark-them'
```

I am trying to do the same with `aiohttp`

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def download(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.content.read(100)

url = 'https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/urllib/request.py'
print(asyncio.run(download(url)))
```

but I am getting a `json` object with keys `payload`, `title`, `locale` from the same URL

```
> python test_aiohttp.py
b'{"payload":{"allShortcutsEnabled":false,"fileTree":{"Lib/urllib":{"items":[{"name":"__init__.py","pa'
```

What is the problem with my usage for `aiohttp` here? It looks like I am missing something fairly obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the aiohttp library correctly. If you the same code with https://google.com or https://github.com/python/cpython (not a file) then a HTML response returned. I think GitHub is returning some API response at that particular URL but I could not find why that is.

Comment: it is likely that `aiohttp` and `urlopen` sent different types of requests (headers) so the website responded differently.